# How to send message to Kafka with Avro serializer and schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send an object to Kafka with Avro serializer and schema registry.
Here is a simplified code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    ...
    props.put(KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put(VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://" + schemaRegistryHostname + ":8081");

    Producer<String, User> producer = new KafkaProducer(properties);

    User user = new User("name", "address", 123);
    ProducerRecord record = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, user);
    producer.send(record);
```

I assumed that the schema is read "behind the scenes" from the registry and the object (user) is serialized, but I get the error below.
What am I missing?
Do I have to read the schema explicitly and send a GenericRecord?

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.getSchema(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDe.java:123) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-3.3.0.jar!/:?]
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:73) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-3.3.0.jar!/:?]
>       at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-3.3.0.jar!/:?]
>       at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:424) ~[kafka-clients-0.9.0.1.jar!/:?]

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct. The only thing that could be missing is that your AVRO object was not properly generated with some AVRO plugin, it means that your class need to implements  `SpecificRecords` which implements `IndexedRecord`.

Comment: Right. Everything seems to work after I created a proper avsc file and generate a Java file from it, using gradle-avro-plugin. I assumed that the schema is created automatically by Avro, using reflection, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct , U must have not created proper structure from avsc file with **mvn generate sources** with maven (pass this command on terminal in your project folder)

Next it will create a bean where u can pass the values as

```
User order = User.newBuilder()
        .setName("xyz")
        .setAddress("CId432")
        .setPrice("123")
        .build();
```